# Distict values from 2 tables combined with aggregating sums from the same two tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to do the following:

- Get distinct name and age from table A and B.
- Then I want to sum up salary from table A and  table B for each set of name and age. I want the output to show: Name, Age, (sum Table A), (sum Table B), (sum Table A- sum Table B)

See the example below:

Table A:

1. Name=Al, Age=20, Salary=10
2. Name=Al, Age=20, Salary=20
3. Name=Bob,Age=22, Salary=25

Table B

1. Name=Al,  Age=20, Salary=30
2. Name=Al,  Age=20, Salary=40
3. Name=Bob, Age=22, Salary=35

Expected output:

1. Name=Al,  Age=20, SalaryA=30, SalaryB=70, difference=-40
2. Name=Bob, Age=22, SalaryA=25, SalaryB=35, difference=-10

How do I write this in SQL? I use Teradata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `group by` and use `union all` to combine results from the queries for tableA and tableB.

```
 select name, age, max(salaryA), max(salaryB), max(salaryA) - max(salaryB) as difference
 from (
 select name, age, sum(salary) as salaryA, null as salaryB
 from tablea 
 group by name, age
 union all
 select name, age, null as salaryA, sum(salary) as salaryB
 from tableb 
 group by name, age) t
 group by name, age
```

Comment: I like your solution, but first time I saw it didnt understand why `MAX()` and didnt saw the `NULL`. Maybe put the `null` in upper case or maybe I need new glasses?

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT A.name, A.age, A.SalaryA, B.SalaryB, A.SalaryA - B.SalaryB as difference
 FROM (
      SELECT name, age, SUM(Salary) as SalaryA
      FROM TableA
      GROUP BY name, age
      ) as A
INNER JOIN 
      (
      SELECT name, age, SUM(Salary) as SalaryB
      FROM TableB
      GROUP BY name, age 
      ) as B
 ON A.name = B.name
AND A.age  = B.age
```